# Reading from a inFile to a list<>

Tags: c#, list, class, filestream

So I have a database program of sorts that reads data from a .txt file into a class object then stores each instance of the class to a list.  But after the first object has been added to the list, each new object that gets added, replaces each previous item in the list with it's data.  So each item in the list is the same.  For instance, if I read in 3 lines from the .txt file:

```
listItem[0] = thirdInstance
listItem[1] = thirdInstance
listItem[2] = thirdInstance
```

if i just read in one item it works fine, listItem[0] = firstInstance.

Here's a snippet of my code, where it happens, it compiles fine and runs without run-time errors, except for what i've mentioned.

```
public void readFromFile()
{
    const string END = "ENDOFWRITE";
    const char DELIM = '|';
    const string fileName = "A1SepDB.txt";
    FileStream inFile = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);
    Customer temp = new Customer();
    string recordIn;
    string[] fields;
    recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
    while (recordIn != END)
    {
        fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
        temp.setFirstName(fields[0]);
        temp.setMiddleName(fields[1]);
        temp.setLastName(fields[2]);
        temp.setAddressLine1(fields[3]);
        temp.setAddressLine2(fields[4]);
        temp.setCity(fields[5]);
        temp.setState(fields[6]);
        temp.setZip(fields[7]);
        temp.setPhoneNumber(fields[8]);
        temp.setAccountType(fields[9]);
        temp.setCustomerSince(Convert.ToDateTime(fields[10]));
        temp.setNextServiceDate1(Convert.ToDateTime(fields[11]));
        temp.setNextServiceDate2(Convert.ToDateTime(fields[12]));
        temp.setNextServiceDate3(Convert.ToDateTime(fields[13]));
        temp.setNextServiceDate4(Convert.ToDateTime(fields[14]));
        ListViewItem listEntry = new ListViewItem();
        listEntry.Text = temp.getFirstName();
        listEntry.SubItems.Add(temp.getLastName());
        listEntry.SubItems.Add(temp.getPhoneNumber());
        CustomerListView.Items.Add(listEntry);
        CustomerList.Add(temp);
        recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
    }
    reader.Close();
    inFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to read contents of a text file into a list of string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `Customer` in each iteration. Right now, you're modifying the *same* instance each time, and then adding another reference to it in the list.

Even though you have three items in the collection, they all point to the same `Customer` instance.

Move your instantiation, so that it occurs inside the `while` loop:

```
while (recordIn != END)
{
    Customer temp = new Customer();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is referencing the same object because your `Customer temp = new Customer();` is outside the while loop. So every time you add a "new" customer to the list, you're actually just changing the same customer object that all list items are referencing.

Move `Customer temp = new Customer();` inside the while loop.

```
    while (recordIn != END)
    {
        Customer temp = new Customer();
        //Do stuff
        CustomerList.Add(temp);
        recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i don't know why i didn't think about that, i should have moved it inside when i put the list initializer inside, i hate when i make careless errors like this. thanks a mil.

Answer (score 0):

```
Customer temp = new Customer();
```

This can not be outside `while` loop

```
//Customer temp = new Customer(); //remove
string recordIn;
string[] fields;
recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
while (recordIn != END)
{
   Customer temp = new Customer();//add
}
```

Comment: thanks, i don't know why i didn't think about that, i should have moved it inside when i put the list initializer inside, i hate when i make careless errors like this.  thanks a mil.

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating temp inside your loop as shown below:

```
public void readFromFile()
{
    const string END = "ENDOFWRITE";
    const char DELIM = '|';
    const string fileName = "A1SepDB.txt";
    FileStream inFile = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);

    string recordIn;
    string[] fields;
    recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
    while (recordIn != END)
    {
        Customer temp = new Customer();
        fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
        temp.setFirstName(fields[0]);
        temp.setMiddleName(fields[1]);
        temp.setLastName(fields[2]);
        temp.setAddressLine1(fields[3]);
        temp.setAddressLine2(fields[4]);
        temp.setCity(fields[5]);
        temp.setState(fields[6]);
        temp.setZip(fields[7]);
        temp.setPhoneNumber(fields[8]);
        temp.setAccountType(fields[9]);
        temp.setCustomerSince(Convert.ToDateTime(fields[10]));
        temp.setNextServiceDate1(Convert.ToDateTime(fields[11]));
        temp.setNextServiceDate2(Convert.ToDateTime(fields[12]));
        temp.setNextServiceDate3(Convert.ToDateTime(fields[13]));
        temp.setNextServiceDate4(Convert.ToDateTime(fields[14]));
        ListViewItem listEntry = new ListViewItem();
        listEntry.Text = temp.getFirstName();
        listEntry.SubItems.Add(temp.getLastName());
        listEntry.SubItems.Add(temp.getPhoneNumber());
        CustomerListView.Items.Add(listEntry);
        CustomerList.Add(temp);
        recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
    }
    reader.Close();
    inFile.Close();
}
```